# Script Python connects and runs queries RMAN (ORACLE) commands

Tags: python, oracle, rman

I want to write code in python to run RMAN (ORACLE) commands. Do you have any samples or tutorials ?

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples of how to run external commands in Python's [subprocess module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

The easiest way of all to run a command (though without any control over I/O) is

```
os.system("command and arguments")
```